# Read/Merge properties file into 1 line, ignoring comments in unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, properties-file

Environment: Unix shell (e.g. BusyBox, using #!/bin/sh)

Task: Read a properties file into a single variable, ignoring comments (#) and empty lines. Replace CR|LF|CRLF with a space.

Properties file, e.g.:

```
a=1

b=2
# comment
c.x.y.z = 3 #ignore this comment, but not the entry
```

Comment: I hope there is a better way than: `grep -v '[[:space:]]*#.*$\|^[[:space:]]*$' "test.properties" | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' ' '`

Comment: Can you move the above comment to the question description?

Comment: Does `awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " } $0 !~ /^#/{ sub("#.*",""); print}' test.properties` get you the expected output?

Comment: @inian nope. it prints just `= 3`